# How to select consistent data from multiple tables efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, transactions, rdbms

I'm using MySQL 5.6. Let's say we have the following two tables:

[image: a class diagram]

Every `DataSet` has a huge amount of child `DataEntry` records that the number would be 10000 or 100000 or more. `DataSet.md5sum` and `DataSet.version` get updated when its child `DataEntry` records are inserted or deleted, in one transaction. A `DataSet.md5sum` is calculated against all of its children `DataEntry.content` s.

Under this situation, What's the most efficient way to fetch consistent data from those two tables?

If I issue the following two distinct SELECTs, I think I might get inconsistent data due to concurrent INSERT / UPDATEs:

1. `SELECT md5sum, version FROM DataSet WHERE dataset_id = 1000`
2. `SELECT dataentry_id, content FROM DataEntry WHERE dataset_id = 1000` -- I think the result of this query will possibly incosistent with the md5sum which fetched by former query

I think I can get consistent data with one query as follows:

```
SELECT e.dataentry_id, e.content, s.md5sum, s.version
FROM DataSet s
INNER JOIN DataEntry e ON (s.dataset_id = e.dataset_id)
WHERE s.dataset_id = 1000
```

But it produces redundant dataset which filled with 10000 or 100000 duplicated `md5sum`s, So I guess it's not efficient (EDIT: My concerns are high network bandwidth and memory consumption).

I think using pessimistic read / write lock (`SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` / `FOR UPDATE`) would be another option but it seems overkill. Are there any other better approaches?

Comment: What is the separation between the application server and the database? Are they on the same machine? Network? What kind of connection do they share? Ethernet? Internet? What speed is the connection?

Comment: They are on different machines, connected via Ethernet LAN and living in same segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join will ensure that the data returned is not affected by any updates that would have occurred between the two separate selects, since they are being executed as a single query.

When you say that md5sum and version are updated, do you mean the child table has a trigger on it for inserts and updates?

When you join the tables, you will get a "duplicate md5sum and version" because you are pulling the matching record for each item in the `DataEntry` table. It is perfectly fine and isn't going to be an efficiency issue. The alternative would be to use the two individual selects, but depending upon the frequency of inserts/updates, without a transaction, you run the very slight risk of getting data that may be slightly off.

I would just go with the join. You can run explain plans on your query from within mysql and look at how the query is executed and see any differences between the two approaches based upon your data and if you have any indexes, etc...

Perhaps it would be more beneficial to run these groups of records into a staging table of sorts. Before processing, you could call a pre-processor function that takes a "snapshot" of the data about to be processed, putting a copy into a staging table. Then you could select just the version and md5sum alone, and then all of the records, as two different selects. Since these are copied into a separate staging table, you wont have to worry about immediate updates corrupting your session of processing. You could set up timed jobs to do this or have it as an on-demand call. Again though, this would be something you would need to research the best approach given the hardware/network setup you are working with. And any job scheduling software you have available to you.

Comment: Unfortunately the alternative without a transaction would not be an option to me because there are many concurrent insert/updates. As for the join option, What do you think about 100000 or more redundant duplicated `md5sum` s? I'm sure I can make query plan efficient with indexes but it may consumes large network bandwidth. It's fine to assume that child table has the trigger which maintains `version` / `md5sum` in the same transaction which makes insert/updates.

Comment: Just to make the point clear - My concerns about the JOIN option are high network bandwidth and memory consumption.

Comment: The amount being returned is fairly negligible really. Your only other option would be to select the md5sum and version as two columns, then you could create a single xml output of the other items as xml blocks of `'<DataEntryItems><DataEntry><dataentry_id>1</dataentry_id><content>abc123etc...</content></DataEntry><DataEntry><dataentry_id>2</dataentry_id><content>morecontent</content></DataEntry></DataEntryItems>'`. This would return 3 columns and 1 row. It would just contain a large clob (or whatever the mysql equiv is of clob) filled with xml.

Comment: Unfortunately, without know a lot more stuff about your project and your hardware and network setup, I can only give these semi-vagueish answers/recommendations... I really don't think the amount of extra data returned in the md5sum and version columns is that big of a deal, but you could get just the version alone, then select all of the DataEntry table items you need and calculate the md5sum on the receiving end instead of in the database...

Comment: It really comes down to tradeoffs, Is the benefit of having the md5sum and version from the database worth the potentially slightly higher network traffic? To answer that you would need to determine what the costs are. Run some load tests and at the least just eyeball the numbers, calculate the average and/or max size of the md5sum and version columns and multiply that by the number of records and see if that is acceptable.

Comment: OK I understand that duplicated data are negligible for most cases. and thanks for the another option in the edit. What do you think about use of `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` / `FOR UPDATE` ? do you think it's overkill?

Comment: The only issue with that would be that you could possibly be slowing down your inserts/updates from your other processes. How frequently do you believe this new process will run? Does it run frequently enough that the locks could interfere with the other processes?

Comment: OK I've got the point - it slows down concurrent inserts/updates, so there are tradeoffs and it looks like I need to do some load tests to see which way is more preferable. To be honest, I'm not quite sure how frequently those processes will run. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- this locks the row
...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

(and check for errors after every statement, including `COMMIT`.)

"100000" is not "huge", but "BIGINT" is.  Recomment `INT UNSIGNED` instead.

For an MD5, make sure you are not using utf8:  `CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  This goes for any other hex strings.

Or, use `BINARY(16)` for half the space.  Then use `UNHEX(md5...)` when inserting, and `HEX(...)` when fetching.

You are concerned about bandwidth, etc.  Please describe your client (PHP? Java? ...).  Please explain how much (100K rows?) needs to be fetched to re-do the MD5.

Note that there is a MD5 function in MySQL.  If each of your items had an MD5, you could take the MD5 of the concatenation of those -- and do it entirely in the server; no bandwidth needed.  (Be sure to increase `group_concat_max_len`)